# Checking if session id ISSET in PDO

Tags: php, pdo, sessionid, isset

I'm switching to PDO prepared statements and I'm having trouble with my code for getting and using session id's.

When a customer registers the session_id is set to equal the user_id (auto-incremented), and session_id is set in the same way when the user returns. This was working properly before switching to PDO, but now session_id aren't being recognized on any subsequent pages (it's viewing 'user_id' as null)

Do I need to switch to using PDO Session Handlers, or is there a way to continue using the method I'm familiar with?

**mysql - This is the code I was using to set session id's in (this worked properly):**

```
// Statements defining $user_name, $password and $hashedPassword (as shown below), and mysql_real_escape_string
// Insert statement
if($result) { 
$qry="SELECT * FROM customer_info WHERE user_name='$user_name' AND password='".sha1($salt + $_POST['password'])."'";
$result=mysql_query($qry);
if($result) {
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 1) {
    session_regenerate_id();
    $member = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $_SESSION['SESS_USER_ID'] = $member['user_id'];
    session_write_close();
    exit();
    } } }
```

**PDO - This is the code I've tried (session id isn't being set):**

```
$user_name = $_POST['user_name'];
$password = $_POST['password'];  
$hashedPassword = sha1($salt . $password); 
$stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO customer_info (...) VALUES(...)');
$stmt->bindParam(':user_id', $user_id); 
...  
$insertResult = $stmt->execute();  
if ($insertResult) {
    $qry="SELECT * FROM customer_info WHERE user_name = $user_name AND password=$hashedPassword";
    if($qry) {
        $affected_rows = $stmt->rowCount();
        if ($affected_rows == 1)  {   
            session_regenerate_id();
            $member = $stmt->fetch();
            $_SESSION['SESS_USER_ID'] = $member['user_id'];   
        }
```

**Additional code that allows me to reference session id on subsequent pages**

**This code is at the top of every subsequent page:**

```
<?php
  //Starts session and checks if the session variable SESS_USER_ID is present or not
  require_once('auth.php');  
  //Database connection and Open database
  require_once('config.php');  
  $user_id = $_SESSION['SESS_USER_ID']; 
?>
```

**auth.php file**

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['SESS_USER_ID']) || (trim($_SESSION['SESS_USER_ID']) == '')) {
    header("location: login_failed.html");
    exit();
}
?>
```

Comment: This isn't the particular problem you're having now, but you need to use full URLs in your `Location:` headers.  Relative paths are broadly supported, but not allowed.

Comment: Why are you calling `session_regenerate_id()`?  Also, can you clarify your question a bit?  Nowhere are you actually setting a session ID... you're just setting some data for your user within the session variable.  If you meant to actually set the session ID, that might be the problem...

Comment: @Brad: I've hopefully clarified the question a bit, but I think you hit the root of the issue :-) The original mysql code sets the session ID (and it works properly), and I've been stumped as to why it doesn't work with PDO. What do I need to do differently?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski: I've rewritten the question so hopefully it's a lot clearer now. When I said before and after I meant before and after switching to PDO ;-) Sorry if that was confusing :-( I'm glad that I was right thought about not needing db session handling :-) One question - I wasn't sure which $stmt you wanted me to include (showing how it's prepared and executed) - were you referring to the statement right before $affected_rows = $stmt->rowCount(); ?

Comment: @ChayaCooper Yes, that's the `$stmt` I meant, since it seems to be where you are setting `SESS_USER_ID`.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski: I just added it :-) But as far as I understand SESS_USER_ID is being set in the statement $_SESSION['SESS_USER_ID'] = $member['user_id'];

Comment: @ChayaCooper Are you certain the `INSERT` statement's `execute()` was successful?  If not, it won't enter that block `if ($affected_rows == 1)` You have debugged `$affected_rows`?

Comment: I haven't thought to debug $affected_rows because the information is being added to the database correctly (including the user_id), and I can fetch the necessary information by user_id.  Do you think I need to debug $affected_rows ?

Comment: @ChayaCooper Because you are basing `if()` logic on the contents of $affected_rows and other variables, print them out to make sure they contain what you expect. And get rid of that `$qry` string which looks to be a remnant of your older `mysql_query()` version since it is adding an additional `if()` enclosure that serves no purpose

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I removed that extra $qry string (thanks for noticing that :-)). Unfortunately it's still not working, but I was able to narrow down the problem a bit. All this troubleshooting finally generated an error message "SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error", and removing these 2 lines removes that message: "$member = $stmt->fetch();$_SESSION['SESS_USER_ID'] = $member['user_id'];"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21966/discussion-between-michael-berkowski-and-chaya-cooper)

Comment: Brr I see unescaped user input in a query :)

Comment: @MichelFeldheim - Would you mind telling me where?

Comment: @MichelFeldheim If you are referring to the `$qry = "SELECT..."`, that isn't actually being executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call to `$stmt->fetch()` is failing because at this point, `$stmt` still refers to the SQL `INSERT` from which you cannot fetch rows.

So what you need to do is execute a `SELECT` statement to retrieve the newly entered user details and `fetch()` from that instead.  Assuming you have an auto-increment column in the `customer_info` table, use `PDO::lastInsertId()` to get the new row's id and use it in your `SELECT` query.

```
$user_name = $_POST['user_name'];
$password = $_POST['password'];  
$hashedPassword = sha1($salt . $password); 
$stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO customer_info (...) VALUES(...)');
$stmt->bindParam(':user_id', $user_id); 
...  
$insertResult = $stmt->execute();  
if ($insertResult && $stmt->rowCount() == 1) {
  // Ok, the INSERT was successful, so now SELECT the row back
  // Use lastInsertId() to get the new row's id
  // Assuming the id column is `user_id`...
  $stmt_user = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM customer_info WHERE user_id = :user_id");
  $stmt_user->bindValue(":user_id", $conn->lastInsertId());
  $stmt_user->execute();

  session_regenerate_id();
  // Fetch from the SELECT query
  $member = $stmt_user->fetch();
  $_SESSION['SESS_USER_ID'] = $member['user_id'];   
}
```

Absent an auto-increment column like I assumed `user_id` to be, you could do the query with `user_name` and `password` by binding the input `$_POST['user_name']` and the `$hashedpassword` just as you had in your original `mysql_*()` code.

Comment: It worked like a charm :-D Thank you so much for all your help, and for your incredible patience in getting to the bottom of this :-)

Comment: Quick question - I'm having trouble getting the SELECT statement to work with $hashedpassword (The error message is "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column"), and I've tried every variation I can think of. Any chance that you can show me how to do it? I'm using a very similar script for logging in, but I obviously have to stick with using the user_name and password for that ;-)

Comment: What is the SELECT statement you are executing? 1054 means either a column is referenced with the wrong table alias in the SELECT list, or doesn't exist at all but is in the SELECT list.

Comment: Sorry for not being more specific :-) I'm trying to use user_name and $hashedpassword instead of user_id in "SELECT * FROM..." I was surprised by that message because obviously those columns exist :-) Even odder, is that the error message shows the name of the unknown column as the hashedPassword. Is the format somehow different then what I'm used to? ("...WHERE user_name=$_POST['user_name'] AND password=$hashedPassword";)

Comment: The query should be to the effect of `SELECT * FROM customer_info WHERE user_name = :user_name and password = :hashedpassword`. You need then to bind each as  `$stmt_user->bindParam(':user_name', $_POST['user_name']); $stmt_user->bindParam(':password', $hashedPassword);`

Comment: Now I get it :-D I was binding it properly, but I hadn't realized that the WHERE statement needed to be structured that way :-) Thank you!

Comment: I'm still having a problem with the password :-( The new error message is "SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined", which is a bit confusing because there's only 2 parameters and I'm binding both :-(

Comment: @ChayaCooper I can't solve that without seeing the code. If you didn't solve it already, that probably warrants a new question including code for only the statement you are trying to execute. Only thing I could guess without code is that you bound params to the wrong statement var `$stmt` (which contains the insert) rather than `$stmt_user` (which contains the select)

Comment: I checked that, and it's being bound to $stmt_user :-( I'll post that question now :-)

Comment: If you want to take a look at the code, I posted the question at http://stackoverflow.com/q/14111958/1056713 :-)

Answer (score 1):

To be very specific to the question

> PDO - This is the code I've tried (session id isn't being set):

```
$user_name = $_POST['user_name'];
$password = $_POST['password'];  
$hashedPassword = sha1($salt . $password); 
$stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO customer_info (...) VALUES(...)');
$stmt->bindParam(':user_id', $user_id); 
...  
$insertResult = $stmt->execute();  
if ($insertResult) {
    $qry="SELECT * FROM customer_info WHERE user_name = $user_name AND password=$hashedPassword";
    if($qry) {
        $affected_rows = $stmt->rowCount();
        if ($affected_rows == 1)  {   
            session_regenerate_id();
            $member = $stmt->fetch();
            $_SESSION['SESS_USER_ID'] = $member['user_id'];   
        }
```

Now look at the code carefully and answer yourself when the session id should be set?
This should be done when:

1) the `$insertResult` isn't `FALSE`

Oh there's an obvious error in your code, so let me stop here and do explain -

`$qry="SELECT * FROM customer_info WHERE user_name = $user_name AND password=$hashedPassword";`

This is merely a dumb string in this case. So you instruction itself comes down to:

```
if ($insertResult) { //Which always will be TRUE regarding result as the string isn't empty!!! 

if ($affected_rows == 1)  {   //if the number of affected rows == 1
```

then do INSERT the Session ID

**What exactly you are doing wrong**

1) You do not track errors, so that you can't catch exact nature of the one
2) You do not execute SQL statement and get result from it
3) In case of row count "failure" you do not track this one, but do ignore this instead

**What you should do instead**

1) Execute the statement : `$qry="SELECT * FROM customer_info WHERE user_name = $user_name AND password=$hashedPassword";` (also the SQL statement contains variables, seems like you got this one from old `mysql_*` functions) like

```
$stmt->prepare("SELECT * FROM customer_info WHERE user_name = :user_name AND password=:hashedPassword LIMIT 1;"); 
$stmt->execute(array(':user_name' => $username, ':hashedPassword' => $hashedPassword))); 
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)

//now check $result if it found the row, like

if ( $result ){
   // found
} else {
   // not found, do track an error here
}
```

2) Again - keep error track. I could suggest you to implement a custom error handler, but for an example sake, you can use an array. 
It would look like this:

```
<?php

//at the bottom of the script
$errors = array();

...
...

if ( $result ){
  // do next stuff
  ...
} else {
  //add an error
  array_push('Incorrect data', $errors);
}
```

then somewhere, you can simply print that errors, like,

```
//We won't use a global keyword
function print_errors(array $errors){

   if ( !empty($errors) ){
        foreach($errors as $error){
           print '<p><li>' . $error . '</li></p>';
        }

   }
}


//Use like this:
print_errors($errors);
```

This will give you a confidence where exactly it does stuck

Comment: Thank you :-) I thankfully got it to work a few minutes ago (kudos to @MichaelBerkowski guidance and patience), but I'm finding the transition from mySql to PDO to be really confusing, so this is really helpful :-)  I’ve been tracking errors (I just hadn’t thought it was important to include the code for that), but adding a custom error handler would be really helpful and thank you for both mentioning it and showing me how to do it. Out of curiosity, why would I need to use fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) instead of fetch()?

Comment: @ChayaCooper you're welcome. PDO::FETCH_ASSOC merely ensures that it would return an associative array as php manual indicates. But this is an optional argument. I used `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` because I expect exactly an associative array, not indexed one.

Comment: And also, remember the "transition" from `mysql_*` functions to PDO isn't that complex thing IF you encapsulate all database abstractions/logic into a class. Say, you used to query SQL server via `mysql_query()` before, and this function is really the very first thing you need. The point here is to emulate something similar to `mysql_query()` via PDO, so it would look like this `$pdoAdapter->query($query, $placeholders)`