# PDO Error "parameter was not defined" even though I've defined and bound that parameter

Tags: select, parameters, pdo, bind

I'm trying to convert this login script from mySql to PDO, and the SELECT statement works fine for user_name but not for password.

The error message displayed is `"SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined`". Do I need to bind $hashedPassword differently for this statement?

```
<?php
session_start(); 
//Include database connection details & salt
$password = $_POST['password'];  
$hashedPassword = sha1($salt . $password); 

try {  
   $stmt_user = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM customer_info WHERE user_name = :user_name and password = :hashedPassword");      

   $stmt_user->bindValue(':user_name', $_POST['user_name'], PDO::PARAM_STR); 
   $stmt_user->bindValue(':password', $hashedPassword);     
   $stmt_user->execute();                 
   session_regenerate_id();                       
   $member = $stmt_user->fetch();
   $_SESSION['SESS_USER_ID'] = $member['user_id'];                    
   session_write_close();
   header("location: launch_member_account.php");
   exit();
}catch(PDOException $e) {
 echo $e->getMessage();
}    
?>
```

Comment: The statement defines the parameter `:hashedPassword` but binds `:password` in the `bindValue()` call. Just change one or the other of them so they match. That's my fault from a comment on your previous question.

Comment: That did it :-D Out of curiosity, should I switch the way I'm binding it in my INSERT/UPDATE statements? I wasn't getting an error message using bindValue(':password', $hashedPassword) for those

Comment: No, the names of them `:password, :hashedPasswod, :username, :whatever` don't matter as long as they match in the SQL statement and the bindValue()/bindParam() call. If they work, leave them.

Comment: Good to know :-D If you want to move this to an answer I'll accept it ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement defines a parameter called `:hashedPassword`, but the `bindValue()` call uses an unknown parameter called `:password`.

```
$stmt_user = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM customer_info WHERE user_name = :user_name and password = :hashedPassword");      
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
// Change this to match the statement.
$stmt_user->bindValue(':hashedPassword', $hashedPassword);
```

It doesn't matter what the parameters are named, as long as they match, so best to just make them consistent across your application.